# How to resize UILabel in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, uilabel, viewdidload

I tried to change `UILabel.frame` with a button and it works correctly:

```
  - (IBAction)changeSize:(id)sender
    {
        CGRect rec = self.labelHello.frame;
        rec = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 300);
        self.labelHello.frame = rec;
    }
```

But if I use the same code in `viewDidLoad` has no effect.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        CGRect rec = self.labelHello.frame;
        rec = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 300);
        self.labelHello.frame = rec;
    }
```

Someone can help me?

Thank's
Stefano

Comment: try it in the viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: @Stefano How you are having label in your view by XIB or by programming? If through XIB you need to do this when your view gets loaded and appears in `viewWillAppear` or if through programming just write this code below the allocation code for the label.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with viewDidAppear but instead works correctly with viewDidAppear.
Thank's a lot!
Stefano

Answer (score 1):

you can cheat with `dispatch_async`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGRect rec = self.labelHello.frame;
        rec = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 300);
        self.labelHello.frame = rec;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in viewwillAppear..it will work...

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with viewDidAppear but instead works correctly with viewDidAppear. Thank's a lot!